# Proving identity about Riemannian curvature applied to itself

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I have been trying to prove the following identity, where $R$ is the curvature tensor (and $E_i$ are normal coordinates centered at a fixed point $p$ with $\nabla X = \nabla Y = \nabla Z = 0$ at $p$):

$$(R_{E_i, X}R)(E_i, Y, Z, W) = R(E_i, X,R(E_i, Y)Z,W) - R(R(E_i, X)E_i, Y, Z, W) - R(E_i, R(E_i, X) Y, Z, W) - R(E_i, Y, R(E_i, X)Z, W)$$

In [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0712.1298.pdf) paper Petersen says in page $5$ that it follows by definition, but I can't see how that's true. By definition, we have:

$$R_{E_i, X}R = (\nabla^2_{X, Y} R- \nabla^2_{Y, X} R)$$

and applying this to $(E_i, Y)Z$ yields only $R(E_i, X)R(E_i, Y)Z $ plus a bunch of terms that don't appear anything like they should be in the equality above. Why is this true?

Comment: Your displayed “by definition” makes no sense.

Comment: @TedShifrin sorry, l forgot to type some stuff. I was referring to the part "We now must unravel the the terms remaining inside the sum. By definition:", which is in page 5 of the pre print I linked, that should be the correct formula

Comment: I'm on mobile now but I'll fix it asap

Comment: @TedShifrin it's fixed now

Comment: The line (the second display) about which I complained is identical.

Comment: @TedShifrin oh, I thought you were referring to the first one. I think it's actually fixed now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long searches I found the following formula, from which the one I'm after follows almost immediately:

$$(R(X, Y)T)(X_1, \cdots, X_k) = -\sum_{i = 1}^{k}T(R(X, Y)X_i, \cdots, X_k)$$